# IOS App auto running in background

Tags: android, ios, background, gps, autostart

I'm developing an IOS / Android gps based application that needs to update location always (or after significant location change).  Similar to Life360 family locator app.  This app doesn't need to start at all and yet when you open the app it has all your location data captured for a week.  If I'm checking on my kids location and they don't have their phone actively running the app, I still get the real-time location and their gps history. 
How is this accomplished? It seems that the app is logging gps data, not only when in foreground and background but when not running at all. Is there a special run-mode these apps use? 
thanks all!
Mike

Answer (score 0):

I can only speak for iOS.

On iOS you can register for significant location changes, and your app will get notified in the background when a location change event occurs (and even get launched in the background if it had been terminated). You can then request background time and transmit your updated location information to your server.

Comment: Thanks Duncan!  Instead of launching the app in the background after a significant location change.  Is there a way to do the same thing on a regular time interval?  i.e. can I wake my app up every 5 minutes to see if my location has changed?  Thanks again!

Comment: No, not for normal apps there's not. Apple prevents that sort of behavior because it would chew through the battery quite rapidly. (If you register your app as a turn-by-turn GPS app you could, but then Apple would reject you because that's not really what your app is doing.)